# ZSH: execute function in a script file

Tags: bash, function, shell, zsh

I have a `~/scripts/git-workflow.sh` file that looks like:

```
#!/bin/zsh

gp() {
  local cmd="git pull"
  echo "=> $cmd"
  $cmd
}
```

It's basically a nicer alias, that will print out the command when I use my alias so I don't forget the actual commands over time.

In my `.zshrc` file, I `source ~/scripts/git-workflow.sh`.

At my zsh prompt, when I execute `$ gp` it seems to run the function but fails.

```
$ gp
=> git pull
gp:5: command not found: git pull
```

However, if I execute `$ git pull` directly on the command-line, it runs just fine.

```
$ git pull
Already up to date.
```

This was working fine when I was using `bash`, but I recently switched to `zsh` (thanks to Apple using it as the default) and have been having issues executing my scripts.

Is there some special format I need to put my function in, or something I need to add to zsh to make this work?

Comment: See [BashFAQ #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) re: why you should never do this (`$cmd`) even in bash. (One of the safe/suggested approaches is the array that @chepner suggests; so that's a cross-shell fix, not just a zsh thing).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: thanks for the link, good info! In my situation I was trying to avoid duplicating the commands in the script to make future refactoring easier. I'm modifying my script to use the array approach instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`zsh` doesn't perform word-splitting on parameter expansions by default, so `git` and `pull` aren't two separate words in the desired command. While you can enable it on a particular parameter expansion, a better approach is to just use an array.

```
gp () {
  local cmd=(git pull)
  echo "=> ${cmd[*]}"
  "${cmd[@]}"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Also try the (z) flag `${(z)cmd}` if you want to execute the command stored in a variable:

> z: Split the result of the expansion into words **using shell parsing** to find the words, i.e. taking into account any quoting in the value. ([Parameter Expansion Flags](https://www.mankier.com/1/zshexpn#Parameter_Expansion-Parameter_Expansion_Flags))

In zsh, word splitting is not performed on parameter (variable) expansion by default.

```
$ x="hello world 'a b c'"

# check the number of arguments with an anonymous function:
# $x is regarded as one argument as a whole
$ () { echo ${#} args; echo ${(F)@} } $x
1 args
hello world 'a b c'
```

`${(z)x}` performs "lexical word splitting", which understands the quotes in the value:

```
$ () { echo ${#} args; echo ${(F)@} } ${(z)x}
3 args
hello
world
'a b c'
```

`${=x}` performs "simple word splitting" based on `IFS`; words are separated at white spaces:

```
$ () { echo ${#} args; echo ${(F)@} } ${=x}
5 args
hello
world
'a
b
c'
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your command line runs bash, but the file you are sourcing is zsh. It is as if you would `#include` in C a C++-include file. This won't work.

In bash, word splitting occurs after `$cmd` is expanded, resulting the command

```
git pull
```

In Zsh, no word splitting occurs after expansion. Hence, the command is understood as

```
'git pull'
```

In your Zsh function, you would have to write

```
${=cmd}
```

This would then do a `git pull`, but of course it would not be valid when seen under bash anymore. I suggest you make up your mind: Do you want it to work under bash, or under Zsh?

If you are working with both shells - I am doing this for instance -, write separte implementations for both shells, except in those cases where bash and Zsh are similar enough that a single implementation would suffice.